# android studio settings.gradle duplicated, not recognized.

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

My android studio project is ostensibly error-free and (usually) builds just fine. But as seen in the following picture, there is a set of files that shows up twice in the file tree:

[image]

...once at the same level as the root project folder, and once within the project folder. NOTE: The actual files on the file system are ONLY located within the project folder.

In Android Studio, when I try to edit the settings.gradle within the project folder, it tells me "This folder does not belong to a Gradle project. Make sure it is registered in settings.gradle.", as shown here:
[image]

So, I try to instead edit the settings.gradle outside the project folder. In that case the Non-Project Files Access window comes up: this file is not part of my project. As shown here:
[image]

Who knew Android Studio was designed by Franz Kafka! But seriously, has anybody seen this? Or do you have any thoughts? Because of this issue, I can't add any new libs, so it is quite a show-stopper.

You may be interested to know that there in my git repo, there are existing versions of several auto-generated files including app.iml and project.iml and some other files from .idea/. When I git checkout back to the ones in the repo, the duplicate-file-trees briefly disappear. (I am still unable to access/edit settings.gradle, though).

If you want more information let me know. Thanks!